# Why do links to social media do not work using html?

Tags: html

I have the following code in my html. When I click on the icon I want to be taken to my websites facebook account.

```
     <li><a href="www.facebook.com/mywebsitename"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria- 
      hidden="true"></i></a></li>
```

However instead I get my webpage without any css and the url changes to the following url. Why is this?

```
      https://mywebiste.com/www.facebook.com/mywebsite
```

Comment: The misspelling in your example URL suggests that maybe you've just missed something.

Comment: Always use the `http(s)://` prefix for absolute URLs, otherwise they will be treated as relative to the current domain. i.e. `<a href="https://www.facebook.com/mywebsitename">`

Comment: Copied it form the address bar https://mywebsite.com/www.facebook.com/mywebsite

Comment: @ZoliSzabó This could be the reason

Answer (score 3):

The **URL** is considered as a **directory Path**. try to replace

```
href="www.facebook.com/mywebsitename"
```

to

```
href="https://www.facebook.com/mywebsitename"
```

Answer (score 1):

Your URL should be starting with a scheme:
`<a href="https://www.facebook.com/mywebsitename">`

See more here: [What_is_a_URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_is_a_URL)

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you didn't write the beginning of the line address. He directs you to your own page in this project because he doesn't know where to go. Use `https://`.

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/mywebsitename">
```